# How to explicitly show that the field momentum fixes momentum conservation in a two charged particle system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, conservation-laws

It is known that in a two charged particle system, where one one particle is charged $q_1$ and moving with velocity $\vec{v}_1$ and the other is charged $q_2$ and moving with velocity $\vec{v}_2$, the forces exerted on each other are equal but not opposite, so that it seems like momentum conservation is broken. Usually, the resolution is that the mechanical momentum plus the field momentum is conserved. However I find it difficult to show this with explicit calculations. This is what I tried to do:

In the $v << c$ regime, the electric field and magnetic field due to these two particles everywhere is

$$\vec{E}_1 = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q_1 \vec{r}}{r^3},
\quad
\vec{E}_2 = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q_2 (\vec{r}-\vec{D})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{D}|^3},
$$

$$\vec{B}_1 = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi }\frac{q_1 \vec{v}_1 \times \vec{r}}{r^3},
\quad
\vec{B}_2 = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi }\frac{q_2 \vec{v}_2 \times(\vec{r}-\vec{D})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{D}|^3}, 
$$

Since the conservation law is

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{P}_{\text{mech}} + \vec{P}_{\text{EM}}\right)
=\oint_S T_{ik}n_k da
$$
To show momentum conservation, I need to show $\oint_S T_{ik}n_k da=0$. This surface integral indeed vanishes if I choose $S$ to be at infinity. However, I think it should vanish as long as $S$ encloses both charged particles. It is a way to show $\oint_S T_{ik}n_k da=0$ for arbitrary $S$?

Comment: "However, I think it should vanish as long as $S$ encloses both charged particles." Why do you think that?

Comment: Can you give references to textbooks or papers where you find these assertions?

Comment: I think the integral should vanish as long as $S$ encloses both particle because momentum conservation should hold as long as both $q_1$ and $q_2$ are in the region of interest which do not require the boundary of the region of interest to be at infinity. Or if the boundary I choose is not at infinity, I'll risk the possibility that either of the charged particles go out of the the boundary?